# knockout.js foreach $data AND $index()?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**HTML**

You can see in the html I am calling editUser with two parameters. $data being the first parameter and $index() being the second.  It should send the current user object in the first parameter and the index of the foreach loop as the second.

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div data-bind="click: $parent.editUser.bind($data, $index())" class="clickable icon black-icon big-icon icon-edit"></div>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: username"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: level"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**Code**

```
    appViewModel.editUser = function( user, index ){
        console.log(user);
        console.log(index);
    };
```

**Output**

```
0
Object{}
```

It completely reverses the parameters somehow. I am at a loss to explain this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `bind` is the function context. So, if you want to pass 2 arguments you're gonna need this:

```
$parent.editUser.bind($data, $data, $index())
```

This way, the `this` in your `editUser` function would be the current item in your `foreach` iteration.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)